# Chrome.storage.local.get not working in the content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I having some trouble maybe one of you can tell me what am I doing wrong. I createad a popup option window for my chrome extension. Its working fine it saves all the settings to chrome.storage.local on button click.. and on load retrieve everything using chrome.storage.local.get and fill the fields on the screen. Problem is when I try to retrieve those settings from the content script its not working (I did this before but as I'm a noobie I lost my code and dont remember how I did it lol - backups... who need them right? lol?

Ok this is my code for saving at popup window

```js
chrome.storage.local.set({['Overlay1']: document.getElementById("osyhkfo1").value}, function() {});
```

this is my code for reading at onload of the options page

```js
      chrome.storage.local.get(['Overlay1'], function(result) {
        if (result.Overlay1){
          document.getElementById("osyhkfo1").value=result.Overlay1; 
        }
      });
```

this is my code in my content script**(here is where the problem is result is always undefine)**

```js
chrome.storage.local.get(['Overlay1'], function(result) {
  this.updatevalues('Overlay1', result.Overlay1);
});
```

updatevalues only save it to a filed that I injected in the mainpage before.

Can you guys help me to find the problem? It makes me crazy because my previous version was working a lost part of my code and now I just can't make it right lol. I try few of the questions already here but couldnt find nothing that applies to my problem.

Thx guys the help of this community is being amazing!

Comment: In the last code block you use a normal `function` so your `this` will be wrong. Switch to arrow syntax.

Comment: hey man thx.. can you give an example of the sintaxe... noobie here dont even know how to search for it

Comment: Problem here is that result is undefined... even if I just set a console.log inside it will no do anything. I Imagine there is some kind of problem with my ready(chrome.storage.local.get)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just a matter of context. I did that at the top of my content_script file. For some reason can't do it. So, I move it down near my fist listenter and worked just fine! Thx guys